# Крэш приложения на андроиде из-за GUILayout.Box(Resources.Load<Texture>())

Tags: android, unity3d, gui

В приложении под андроид происходят периодические вылеты при переходе из сцены с `GUILayout.Box(Resources.Load<Texture>())` на любую другую сцену. Вылеты произвольные, какой-либо закономерности у них нет. Могут случаться раз в 30 кликов, а могут и на второй-третий.
Logcat выдает

```
02-09 04:51:02.254 F/libc    ( 2181): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000020 (code=1), thread 2245 (UnityPreload)    
02-09 04:51:02.310 I/DEBUG   (  173): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
02-09 04:51:02.310 I/DEBUG   (  173): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:4.4.4/KTU84P/eng.genymotion.20160825.201657:userdebug/test-keys'
02-09 04:51:02.310 I/DEBUG   (  173): Revision: '0'
02-09 04:51:02.310 I/DEBUG   (  173): pid: 2181, tid: 2245, name: UnityPreload  >>> com.TEST.IMGU <<<
02-09 04:51:02.310 I/DEBUG   (  173): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000020
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     eax 00000000  ebx 950b0ba4  ecx b85d6808  edx b85d5c00
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     esi b8522aa0  edi 00000c08
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     eip 9429253c  ebp 8ecb6ad8  esp 8ecb6a60  flags 00210282
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173): 
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173): backtrace:
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #00  pc 0052153c  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #01  pc 005212da  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #02  pc 0051b9c2  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #03  pc 00375d8f  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #04  pc 00378418  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #05  pc 00378207  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #06  pc 003781b0  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #07  pc 003deb59  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #08  pc 0000bc7c  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+236)
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #09  pc 0003e295  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_clone+69)
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #10  pc 003deadf  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #11  pc 0035c0e7  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #12  pc 003f941f  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #13  pc 0045f2cf  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #14  pc 00280767  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #15  pc 001cddef  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #16  pc 001cdb57  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #17  pc 001cd90f  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #18  pc 001cd677  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #19  pc 001cd42f  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #20  pc 001cd1e7  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #21  pc 001ccf9f  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #22  pc 001ccd57  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #23  pc 001ccb0f  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #24  pc 001cc8c7  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #25  pc 001cc67f  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #26  pc 001cc437  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #27  pc 001d0377  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #28  pc 001d012f  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #29  pc 001d0f27  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #30  pc 001d0cdf  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #31  pc 001b82ef  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173): 
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173): stack:
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a20  951f9e60  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a24  b853ff50  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a28  0000073f  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a2c  8ecb6a44  [stack:2245]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a30  951fa734  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a34  00000000  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a38  b8c264d0  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a3c  950b0ba4  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a40  46505845  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a44  950b0ba4  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a48  8ecb6a68  [stack:2245]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a4c  93e5ce29  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a50  951f8ce0  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a54  b853ff50  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a58  00000025  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a5c  94292521  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #00  8ecb6a60  950b0ba4  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a64  950b0ba4  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a68  8ecb6ad8  [stack:2245]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a6c  94293928  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a70  b853ff50  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a74  00000025  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a78  00001000  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a7c  b853ff50  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a80  0000073f  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a84  00000000  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a88  000001d0  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a8c  0000009a  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a90  b8ab0580  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a94  0000073f  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a98  00000014  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6a9c  950b0ba4  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          ........  ........
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #01  8ecb6ae0  b8522aa0  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6ae4  b85d6808  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6ae8  0000009a  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6aec  00000002  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6af0  0000018a  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6af4  00000013  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6af8  00000002  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6afc  00000100  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b00  94dcd88a  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b04  b85d5c00  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b08  00000c08  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b0c  b85d6808  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b10  00000006  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b14  950b0ba4  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b18  b877431c  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b1c  94dc25d6  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          ........  ........
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):     #02  8ecb6b70  b8522aa0  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b74  0000009a  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b78  00000001  
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b7c  94dc3c37  /data/app-lib/cRom.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b80  b85da45c  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b84  b85da462  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b88  8ecb6c68  [stack:2245]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b8c  b8522aa0  [heap]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b90  8ecb6c30  [stack:2245]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b94  950b0ba4  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b98  8ecb6c98  [stack:2245]
02-09 04:51:02.458 I/DEBUG   (  173):          8ecb6b9c  940e6d90  /data/app-lib/com.TEST.IMGUI-1/libunity.so
```

Сам метод:

```
   private void OnGUI() {
        GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(widthForRightPanel, height, widthForRightPanelEnd, heightEnd), GUI.skin.box);
        scrollPosition = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition, false, false);
        GUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
        GUILayout.Box(Resources.Load<Texture>("ViewerImages\\smallest\\image processing"), customSkin.box);
        GUILayout.EndVertical();
        GUILayout.EndScrollView();
        GUILayout.EndArea();
    }
```

Если в Box просто текст вбить, то все работает нормально. Вылеты происходят как на эмуляторе, так и на обычных устройствах. Если на устройстве в Developer options, в Monitoring выставить Enable OpenGL traces - call stack on glGetError, приложение начинает сильно тормозить, и вылеты прекращаются полностью. Десктопная версия работает нормально без вылетов, даже на относительно древних компах.

Собственно вопрос как пофиксить, или есть ли другой механизм для вывода изображений в рантайме (c GUI.Box такая же хрень).

Comment: `Resources.Load<Texture>` грузит текстуру с диска. То есть, у вас обращение к диску идёт при каждом обновлении гуя - что может происходить несколько раз в кадр, то есть очень быстро. Вероятно, просто не успевает загрузиться. Не уверен, что дело в этом, просто предположение. В любом случае, текстуру надо загрузить единожды, и не насиловать бедную флешку :) Кстати, а чего не Unity UI?

Comment: Да, причина оказалась в этом, спасибо :) По поводу Unity UI - у меня должно быть два слоя. На первый из XML парсится меню с разделами и кнопками. Каждой кнопке соответствует еще одна XML с контентом. При клике на кнопку на второй слой распарсивается контент из изображений и текста. Я сначала попытался сделать все это через unity UI, но там оказались проблемы с размерами текстовых блоков, картинок и отступов между ними, которые с лету я решить не смог. Времени было мало, поэтому я просто решил использовать слои, на которых все автоматом группируется.

Comment: Все проблемы с отступами в Unity UI - это проблемы с якорями. Разберитесь с ними, и вы проникнетесь неимоверной крутизной "нового" UI :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выношу из комментариев.

Метод `Resources.Load<Texture>` грузит текстуру с диска. То есть, у вас обращение к диску идёт при каждом обновлении GUI - что может происходить несколько раз в кадр, то есть очень быстро. В некоторых случаях текстура просто не успевает загрузиться.

Кроме того, это само по себе некорректно - в цикле грузить ресурс с ПЗУ в каждой итерации.

Вот так проблемы быть не должно:

```
private void OnGUI() 
{
     var boxTexture = Resources.Load<Texture>("ViewerImages\\smallest\\image processing");

     GUILayout.BeginArea(new Rect(widthForRightPanel, height, widthForRightPanelEnd, heightEnd), GUI.skin.box);
     scrollPosition = GUILayout.BeginScrollView(scrollPosition, false, false);
     GUILayout.BeginVertical(GUI.skin.box);
     GUILayout.Box(boxTexture, customSkin.box);
     GUILayout.EndVertical();
     GUILayout.EndScrollView();
     GUILayout.EndArea();
}
```

Да, в этом случае объявление `boxTexture` тоже находится внутри цикла, но компилятор это оптимизирует, и значение будет присвоено единожды. В исходном примере оптимизация не произведётся.